# Does it look like a Fake iPhone 6 or original? Specially The accessories. I'm confused with power adapter (rounded Pin)

Tags: iphone, power, charger, lightning, accessories

Does it look like a Fake iPhone 6 or original? Specially The accessories. I'm confused with power adapter (rounded Pin).  I have only this two images. Thanks

**I just needed info on the USB charging brick. Is it possible that it can be original? Rounded Pin confused me, I never saw this kind of brick shape with rounded pins.**

[image: Back]

[image: Front]

Comment: The adapter is a European compatible plug. If you purchase an iPhone in most European (and other) countries, this is the adapter. USA has different power outlets, thus different adapters (UK even more different )

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, there is no way to tell with such low quality images, you would need to be hands on with the device.

Looking at the accessories would not really help as those could be cheap replacements that are fake with a real iPhone.

You need to have a look at the device hands on and download some apps on the App Store and try logging into FaceTime and calling another Apple device.

In case you are considering purchasing this, please make sure the device is not logged into iCloud Find My iPhone, otherwise this could indicate the device is stolen, and in future you won't be able to use the device if you erase it and try to set it up again from scratch.

EDIT: Regarding the actual power adapter it self, this is a European iPhone power adapter but it does look significantly different from what is on Apple's website: https://www.apple.com/support/usbadapter-european/

Comment: I have a iphone 6s+ and that is not the original power adapter - the round pins are well, seem to be for Switzerland, but the body length is too short and too rounded...